# Why does $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2+x+1\rangle}$ have $25$ elements, but $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x-1\rangle}$ have $5$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why does $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x^2+x+1\rangle}$ have $25$ elements, but $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle x-1\rangle}$ have $5$ elements? I understand this must come from the degrees of the polynomials generating these ideals, but I don't fully understand how.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the second, every quadratic polynomial can be written as 
$$
p(x) = q(x) (x - 1) + r(x)
$$
by the long-division algorithm, and in this decomposition, $\deg(r) < 1$; that means that $r$ is a constant, and there are only five choices.

A parallel argument for the second shows that every item can be written as a product with a remainder that's a *linear* polynomial $ax + b$ in $x$, and the 5 choices for each of $a$ and $b$ provide your 25 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the viable representatives in the quotient, $a\overline{x}+b$ with $a,b\in\Bbb Z_5$ for the former and $a$ with $a\in\Bbb Z_5$ for the latter. That's $25$ choices for the first and $5$ for the second.

Comment: Apparently Hugheses all think the same way. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes Clearly the best way. ;)

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x^2+x+1)\cong \mathbb Z_5[\alpha]$ where $\alpha$ root of $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ and degree of extension $\mathbb [\mathbb Z_5[\alpha]:\mathbb Z_5]=2$ then number of element is $5^2=25$ .

But $\mathbb Z_5[x]/(x-1)\cong \mathbb Z_5[1]\cong \mathbb Z_5$